# No puedo guardar la imagen en la ruta de la carpeta error: Notice: Undefined index: foto in C

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Trato de guardar la imagen en un directorio por fuera de este directorio llamado `img`, sucede que no guarda y me manda el mismo error no encuentro como guardo la imagen. Me pueden ayudar a visualizar el error, en el siguiente código.

**registro_categoria.php**

```
    <?php
    if (isset($con))
    {
?>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="nuevoCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Agregar nuevo catalogo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="guardar_categoria" name="guardar_categoria" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="resultados_ajax"></div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="foto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Foto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="file" class="form-control" id="foto" name="foto">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" required>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Descripción</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion"   maxlength="255" ></textarea>

            </div>
          </div>







      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar_categoria">Guardar datos</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

**categorias.js**

```
$( "#guardar_categoria" ).submit(guardar_categoria) 

function insertarImagen(evento){
    evento.preventDefault()
    var datos = new FormData($("#guardar_categoria")[0])
    $("resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...")
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/nueva_categoria.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: datos,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos)
        }
    })
}
```

**nueva_categoria.php**

```
<?php
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/*Inicia validacion del lado del servidor*/

if(empty($_POST['nombre'])) {
       $errors[] = "Nombre vacío";  
    } else if (!empty($_POST['nombre'])){
    /* Connect To Database*/
    require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code


    $nombre=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["nombre"],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $descripcion=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["descripcion"],ENT_QUOTES)));                  
    $date_added=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $foto=$_FILES["foto"];
        if ($foto["type"] == "img/jpg" OR $foto["type"] == "img/jpeg" ) {
            $ruta = "img/".md5($foto["tmp_name"]).".jpg";        
    $sql="INSERT INTO categorias (foto, nombre_categoria, descripcion_categoria,date_added) VALUES ('$ruta','$nombre','$descripcion','$date_added')";
    $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if ($query_new_insert){
            move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $ruta);
            echo "El catalogo ha sido ingresada satisfactoriamente.";
        } else{
            $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
        }
    } else {
        $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
    }
    }
    if (isset($errors)){

        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>Error!</strong> 
                <?php
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                            echo $error;
                        }

                    ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        if (isset($messages)){

            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($messages as $message) {
                                echo $message;
                            }
                        ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
```

?>

Comment: prueba este orden move_uploaded_file(rutaInicial, rutaFinal)

Comment: intente con move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $ruta); sin embargo sale el mismo error.  Notice: Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\stock\ajax\nueva_categoria.php on line 17

Comment: La meta es guardar la foto en el directorio "img" y la ruta guardarla en mysql para luego mostrarla en html.

Answer (score 0):

Hola revice tu código y encontré algunos errores como duplicado de la id '`guardar_categoria`' en el html, no deverias darle la misma id al formulario y al `button` (el boton no es un formulario) y donde esta definida la funcion que llamas en esta linea `$( "#guardar_categoria" ).submit(guardar_categoria)` deverias llamar a la funcion `insertarImagen`, corrige lo que te comento y me cuentas si te resulta saludos

Comment: kevin gracias por su ayuda, pero genera el mismo error:

Comment: y has echo un 'echo' a la variable aver que llega

Comment: le agrego "isset" a $foto=isset($_FILES["foto"]; y no me genera el error undefined index pero si me genera un error: " error desconocido" anidado en el archivo nueva categoria.php despues de hacer el insert into a la tabla categorias

Answer (score 0):

kevin gracias por su ayuda, pero genera el mismo error: cambie el id del botón submit por "guardar_datos" y en el js:
                                                            $(

```
"#guardar_categoria" ).submit(function(event){
$('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true); 

    var datos = new FormData($("#guardar_categoria")[0])
    $("resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...")
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/nueva_categoria.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: datos,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(datos){
            $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
            $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
            load(1);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault()
})
```

y el boton de submit quedo con el id=guardar_datos                                `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar_datos">Guardar datos</button>`

pero si llegando el mismo error:

> Notice: Undefined index: foto in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\stock\ajax\nueva_categoria.php on line 17

Comment: Hola Jeinner, te comento que StackOverflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, por tanto, cada reply a la pregunta **debe ser una respuesta que resuelva/ayude a resolver** el problema planteado. Si deseas agregar información a tu pregunta, puedes [editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/88101/edit) y agregar el código con su **correspondiente formato**. Ver [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).